# OpenId IdentityServer AutoLogin

Tags: identityserver4, openid, claims-based-identity

I wanted to see if there is a way to Autologin a user where they have a `ClientID` and `ClientSecret`. I can get a `TokenClient` but once I get that I am not sure what I can do in order to AutoLogin a user.

```
var client = new TokenClient(string.Concat(this.BaseAddress, IdentityServerTokenServiceUrl), ClientId, ClientSecret, AuthenticationStyle.PostValues);
```

Comment: For user authentication you'll be wanting to use the authorize endpoint and a grant type like `'implicit` or `authorization_code`. I'd suggest watching this vid (by one of the authors of IdentityServer4) as a good into into what OIDC is and how it works: https://vimeo.com/113604459

Comment: @mackie is there any explain to can try ?